# share ExecutionHandler in different ChannelPipeline

Tags: java, netty

My server has two different type clients which has different message format, so there are two NioServerSocketChannelFactory in server which handle two type clients requests respectively. These two type clients need to access a same object in two NioServerSocketChannelFactory's handler. Can I share same OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor object in two ChannelPipelines?

for example:

```
Channels.pipeline(
    concurrencyHandler,
    new Handler1());
}

Channels.pipeline(
    concurrencyHandler,
    new Handler2());
}
```

Will OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor take care of thread concurrency when handler1 & 2 access a same object?

Answer (score 1):

You should use one ExecutionHandler per ChannelFactory as the OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor use the Channel id to lookup the right Executor for a given Channel. A Channel id is only unique per ChannelFactory so you could have bad side effects if you share it across different ChannelFactories.

Comment: It use Channel object to be key not Channel's id.

Comment: The code I read is 3.3.1, getChildExecutorKey returns a Channel object. Trustin says OMATPE will care thread synchronization, but I have not found synchronized keyword or something else. How did it do that?

Comment: It use a LinkedTransferQueue for this which use CAS

Comment: @jean sorry I dont get your explantation.. If you think there is abug please open a issue at our issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

Share OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor in two ChannelFactory can not make synchronization between threads. Channel has its exclusive task queue, OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor only make sure one channel's event (task in the queue) are executed orderly. It can not prove tasks in two channel's two task queue execute orderly. Task in different queue access one object can not be synchronized.